# How to store ontology's TBOX and ABOX and where should the reasoning take place?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, ontology, virtuoso, triplestore

I am working on a semantic IoT architecture that comprises of some services some services. The goal is to add semantic annotation using an ontology which I built on Protege. I am also using Virtuoso 6 set up on an Ubuntu 18.04 server along with Jena 3.6 API (Java 8) with Pellet reasoner. I understand it is best practice to keep TBOX and ABOX split so that the reasoning and SPARQL querying should be faster, but how am I supposed to do that using Virtuoso? So given my ontology in `.owl` file along with all the individuals I have how am I supposed to store my TBOX and how my ABOX and at what phase should the reasoning take place?

At first  the way I built my architecture was that every time I had to make a SPARQL request I would send to Jena which would in turn take the graph that is uploaded on Virtuoso, and then make a query using the reasoner, which would eventually return the results.

My professor, however, did not agree with this approach, as he stated that it is not fast enough, and suggested I change my architecture to a one that does reasoning only when necessary and not every time I have to make a SPARQL query. So I am asking how to use Virtuoso (or any other triple store) to generally store my ontology in an efficient way.

Comment: Virtuoso 6 was last updated to `6.1.8` in December 2013, and is long outdated. Upgrading to a current Virtuoso 7 (initially shipped in April 2013; updated to `7.2.6` in recent months; available as both Open Source and Enterprise Editions) or Virtuoso 8 (initially shipped in September 2017; recently updated to `8.3`; currently available only as Enterprise Edition) is *strongly* recommended. If such upgrade is impossible for you, we would be interested to learn why!

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04 that is why and I get that versions 7 and 8 of virtuoso are compatible only for windows. Is that correct?

Comment: Package management for Ubuntu and other Linux distros has lagged far behind the software. Prebuilt binaries for your environment are available, for either [Enterprise Edition (with a trial license)](https://shop.openlinksw.com/license_generator/virtuoso/?serverVersionSelection=8.3&opsysFamilySelection=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fontology%2Fsoftware%23GenericLinux&opSystemSelection=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.openlinksw.com%2Foplweb%2Fopsys%2Fx86_64-generic-linux-glibc25-64%23this) or [Open Source Edition](https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuoso/files/virtuoso/7.2.6-dev/).

Answer (score 0):

Virtuoso supports Named Graphs (since it's an RDF Quad store in its RDF DBMS aspect).

Just load your TBox Triples into one Named Graph and then your ABox Triples into another.

Reasoning and inference in Virtuoso is offered in two forms. In either case, it's controlled by pragmas; i.e., you turn it on and off as required:

1. Built-In -- see this post about [Built-In Reasoning and Inference](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/harmonizing-disparate-rdbms-data-using-virtuosos-built-in-reasoning-and-inference-functionality/887)
2. Custom -- See this post about [Custom Reasoning and Inference](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/virtuoso-8-0-creating-a-custom-inference-rules-using-spin-vocabulary-d7a060f859ef)

Note: both posts demonstrate the utility of the Virtuoso approach with live examples.

Comment: I see the second post use virtuoso 8. I should have mentioned I use virtuoso 6.

Answer (score 0):

In an IoT deployment, values are typically changing constantly, hence a live querying approach may be appropriate. So if you neglect the live reasoning aspect for a second (maybe you can precompute it as the dynamic aspects of the IoT deployment are not relevant in the reasoning you want to do), you can do with a query like:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>
SELECT ?value
FROM <http://my-fancy-iot-device/temperature-sensor-abox>
FROM <http://my-ldp-server/the-reasoned-tbox>
WHERE {
  ?x a ?sensor ; rdf:value ?value .     # from the 1st source and changes often
  ?sensor rdfs:subClassOf sosa:Sensor . # from the 2nd source and changes seldom
}
```

You need a SPARQL engine that interprets the name of the graph in the `FROM` part in a way that does an HTTP request to said graph name, eg. [roqet](http://librdf.org/rasqal/roqet.html). Reasoning can also be introduced, but there roqet would not be sufficient.